# The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, google-cloud-firestore, release

Flutter app running in debug mode fine. Errors on releasing the app.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         1434.8s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin android_intent...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                        93.5s


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_intent'.
```

What I have tried:

1. Removed 'android_intent' plugin. After removing, still having the same issue with cloud_firestore.

```
                                                                                                                   
* What went wrong:                                                                                                 
Execution failed for task ':flutter_appavailability:verifyReleaseResources'.                                       
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade                  
   > Android resource linking failed                                                                               
     /home/mkmalik/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fa16a5b23fa3b0f70fd87fe1ad317210/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
                                                                                                                   
     /home/mkmalik/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fa16a5b23fa3b0f70fd87fe1ad317210/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                   
* Try:                                                                                                             
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                                                                   
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                                                                         
                                                                                                                   
BUILD FAILED in 6m 38s                                                                                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                                                           
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     407.1s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the
incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

2. Updated Gradle to 4.0.1 and compileSdkVersion to 30. And managed to release the app (with 7 warnings from native code). But on the device, it immediately stops (only white screen) after a sec.

**Flutter 1.22.5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem were with flutter_appavailability.
Just removed and problem solved.